# Changing appearance of UIBarButtonItem also changes position of navigationbar and toolbar?

Tags: ios, ios5, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem, uiappearance

once again I have a problem with my custom navigation- and toolbar:
I've customised their tintColor and the font by using the appearance proxy in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. Initially the bars should be hidden by setting their center outside the visible area in `viewDidLoad`. By single-tapping I use my own animation to slide the bars in/out. 
 Everything was working just fine until the next step: 
I wanted the UIBarButtonItems to have the same font like i used in the bars, so I went back to `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and added the following code:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
[UIFont fontWithName:FONT_HEADER size:0.0],UITextAttributeFont,nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

It works just fine for the font part, but somehow it also sets the bars back into the visible position before `viewWillAppear` so the bars are not initially hidden anymore. I tried to find out what causes this unmeant repositioning and couldn't find any connection. I also tried to reset the position at some later point like `viewWillAppear` but this somehow doesn't work for the toolbar.
 
EDIT: The described behaviour does only occur on devices with iOS 5 though. On the iOS6 simulator everything still seems fine.

Does anyone have a hint for me what is going wrong here or how I could smoothly solve this problem? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
   [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
[UIFont fontWithName:FONT_HEADER size:0.0],UITextAttributeFont,nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

what's the FONT_HEADER here? Did you check if the ios 5 support this font?

Comment: FONT_HEADER is just a defined macro with the font name. In the meantime I tried out some things and it turned out, that using size:0.0 caused the trouble for me. Setting it to a font size != 0.0 did the trick.